# how to run java apps in windows using docker

Tags: java, docker

hi all i have an application and have an docker file like this :

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
COPY ./build/libs/nasapicture-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/app/
WORKDIR /usr/app
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "nasapicture-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"]
```

in my local i use windows 10 as my OS. and for java version i use java 11. and i have install docker in my local.

but when i run like this

```
$ docker build -t nasa-picture .
```

but i got error like this :

```
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 215B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/java:8-jdk-alpine                                               5.4s
 => [auth] library/java:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => CANCELED [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/java:8-jdk-alpine@sha256:d49bf8c44670834d3dade17f8b84d709e7db47f1887f67  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/java:8-jdk-alpine@sha256:d49bf8c44670834d3dade17f8b84d709e7db47f1887f671a0e098ba  0.0s
 => => sha256:d49bf8c44670834d3dade17f8b84d709e7db47f1887f671a0e098bafa9bae49f 947B / 947B                         0.0s
 => => sha256:3fd9dd82815ca4510a34bafef556815c440bcff37827d8495639137aeb145a36 3.29kB / 3.29kB                     0.0s
 => ERROR [2/3] COPY ./build/libs/nasapicture-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/app/                                         0.0s
------
 > [2/3] COPY ./build/libs/nasapicture-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/app/:
------
failed to compute cache key: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount266707143/build/libs: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount266707143/build/libs: no such file or directory
```

my question is how to run java apps in local docker using windows ?

Comment: You have problems with your docker installation.

Comment: Do you in fact have the file `./build/libs/nasapicture-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` on your local system, relative to the directory you're running `docker build .`?